# Vidyo SDK unexpected disconnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-conferencing, vidyo

I downloaded the Vidyo SDK for iOS. I followed the all the steps to generate a new token and succeeded on that. But at the time of joining the call it always prompting **Unexpected disconnection**. Even in the `VidyoConnector` Mac app also getting same error. Led to conference inability.

What are all the possibilities of hitting this error. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems like the token you have generated is invalid. How did you generate it ? Here is a link that provides with token generation scripts samples in multiple languages.
https://support.vidyo.io/hc/en-us/articles/115003127747-Generate-a-Token
Another tip to validate your token - it's a long string that ends with "==" symbol.

Comment: Could you post an example in your answer how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the python script shared at https://static.vidyo.io/4.1.16.8/utils/generateToken.py
The syntax for using our pyton token generation:- python3 generateToken.py --key= --appID= --userName= --expiresInSecs=10000
Make sure that you do not include any special character like @ in the user name